# Using smaller tantalum capacitors in parallel vs a single large aluminum cap for decoupling

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design

I'm designing a circuit that will connect to a series of WS2812b LEDs.  The recommendation is to use a 1000μF aluminum cap as a decoupler between +5V and GND just in front of the first LED to prevent surge damage when powered on.  I have a perfboard circuit setup that way and it works fine.  I'm looking to shrink the whole thing down onto an SMD PCB and wondered if I could use 2-3 smaller tantalum caps in parallel instead.

Basically, are these equivalent circuits?

[image]

Comment: Aren't tantalums pretty bad at surges?

Comment: My understanding is that they're problematic with large overvoltage situations, but I don't believe initial DC surge is an issue for them.  I could be wrong on that, though.

Comment: Pedantic note: 330µF x3 does not equal 1000 Farads! :)  It should work, but note that many a tantalum has fried from experiencing even a slight reverse bias.

Comment: @rdtsc - hah yes, should be 1000uF.  1000F is quite a cap!  Didn't consider how it would handle the reverse.

Comment: @JesseWilliams please edit your question to reflect the correct value of the capacitor -- then it won't confuse future generations.

Comment: If you're just looking for a different form factor (i.e., not too tall, but you can afford to grow out) you could use multiple aluminum caps.

Comment: @TimWescott - fixed the image. And I have considered that - which may be the option I go with in the long run.